# In Java code conventions, the instance variables should be placed before the methods or after the methods?

Tags: java, coding-style

In Java code conventions, the instance variables should be placed before the methods or after the methods? I know, in the code convention of Oracle or Apache, they recommend the instance variables should be placed before the methods. However, in the book of Core Java, the authors place the instance variables after the methods. Hmm...maybe because of my C++ background, during my learning C++, I am educated that public functions should be placed before private members, because people care more about the functionality your code provide. Therefore, I want to know which is preferred way? If you can explain your reasons using your experiences of practical projects, that's better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal Java convention is to put static variables first, instance variables, followed by constructors, and then the methods last.

> However, in the book of Core Java, the authors place the instance variables after the methods.

You can always find people / books that don't follow the normal conventions.

> Therefore, I want to know which is preferred way?

See above.

> If you can explain your reasons using your experiences of practical projects, that's better.

No reason, apart from the fact that this is the *accepted* normal way of doing it, and writing code that goes against the normal conventions *tends* to make it less readable ... for people who follow the normal conventions.

It is possible that someone has done some empirical studies of code readability in which they measured relative readability.  But I've never bothered to search them out.

Comment: +1 I always fields before they are used even if I am not following convention. (In other words I miss method local fields ;)

Comment: I strongly doubt any such studies on code readability exist -- as the code later is mediated by an IDE which breaks it down for you.

Comment: I think 'apart from the fact that this ist the accepted normal way of doing it, and writing code that goes against the normal conventions tends to make it less readable ...' is the key point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the style of the project you are working on. Most coding conventions are there so people can avoid thinking about small code-formatting problems constantly (and source-control stepping on other people's source in non-constructive ways). So if you work in a project, and the project already uses a convention, stick to it.

[Oracle/Sun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137946.html#182) uses "attributes first". [Android guidelines](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#define-fields-in-standard-places) propose either at start, or just before the methods that use them. I tend to use Oracle/Sun guidelines for my own projects, since the JDK source is always 1 click away.

Comment: I think I will agree with your first statement.Additionally, thanks for your links.